# Expectation of the absolute value of sum of $n$ Rademacher variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_i$ be independent Rademacher variables for $i=1,\cdots,n$, and
$$S=E\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|\right]$$
How to estimate $S$ in terms of $n$?

There is a similar question on this site but it doesn't give a precise bound. I have found that $$S=\Theta\left(\sqrt \frac {2}{\pi} n^{1/2}\right)$$ on some literature but I have no idea to prove it.

Comment: Assuming the $\{X_i\}$ variables are i.i.d. with zero mean and finite variance, you can apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you.

Comment: What is $\Theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{Y_n\}$ with $Y_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a simple symmetric random walk and its expected absolute distance after $n$ steps is [given by](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html)
$$
\mathsf{E}|Y_n|=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\binom{n}{\lceil n/2\rceil}\sim \sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi}}.
$$